# Which getty should I use for /dev/tty1 - tty6 text consoles in linux, agetty or something other

Tags: linux, tty, init, getty

I'm configuring LFS linux and I want to select right "getty" for `/etc/inittab` to handle  text consoles /dev/tty1 - /dev/tty6 (the text consoles handled by linux kernel, with output on first display).

There is `agetty`, is it good for tty1, or it is limited only for modems like ttyS0?

If I should use other implementation of getty, what is the package name?

Comment: `agetty` works for any `tty`.

Comment: TNW, thanks, but are there other classic variants?

Comment: That comment-question is answered at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255385/ .