# What is the difference between getty and agetty?

Tags: command, getty

When I looked in the manual for agetty all I saw was `alternative getty`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There was a program named `getty` in 1st Edition Unix.  The BSDs usually have a program named `getty` that is a (fairly) direct descendant of this.  It (nowadays) reads `/etc/ttys` for the database of configured terminal devices and `/etc/gettytab` for the database of *terminal line types* (a line type being passed as an argument to the `getty` program).

The Linux world has a collection of clones and reimplementations, as did minix before it.

- `agetty` was written by Wietse Venema, as an "alternative" to AT&T System 5 and SunOS `getty`, and ported to Linux by Peter Orbaek (who also provided `simpleinit` alongside it).  It is suitable for use with serial devices, with either modems or directly connected terminals, as well as with virtual terminal devices.
- Paul Sutcliffe, Jr's `getty` and `uugetty` is hard to find nowadays, but was an alternative to `agetty`.  (The `getty-ps` package containing them both can still be found in SlackWare.)
- Fred van Kempen wrote an "improved" `getty` and `init` for minix in 1990.
- Gert Doering's `mgetty` is another getty that is suitable for use with actual serial devices, and was designed to support "smart" modems such as fax-modems and voice-modems, not just "dumb" terminal-only modems.
- Florian La Roche's `mingetty` was designed *not* to support serial devices, and generic getty functionality on any kind of terminal device.  Rather, it is specific to virtual terminal devices and cuts out all of the traditional getty hooplah that is associated with modems and serial devices.
- Felix von Leitner's `fgetty` was derived from `mingetty`, adjusted to use a C library with a smaller footprint than the GNU C library, and tweaked to include things like the `checkpasswd` mechanism.
- Nikola Vladov's `ngetty` was a rearchitecture of the whole getty mechanism.  Instead of `init` (directly or indirectly) knowing about the TTYs database and spawning multiple instances of getty, each to respond on one terminal, init spawns one `ngetty` process that monitors all of the terminals.

Comment: Completely forgot about this question, but I appreciate the extended answer.

Comment: but mingetty works on serial devices

Answer (score 1):

`agetty` does not use `/etc/gettydefs` where `getty` uses `/etc/gettydefs`.