# When will login terminate?

Tags: linux, login

When starting up an OS, `getty` and `login`  are run. It seems that login will continuously run after finish logging in.

There is no `logout` command. I wonder when `login` will terminate running, except when shut down the OS?

Btw, is it correct that `login` only runs on text console, not when starting X windows and a display manager and a desktop environment?

Thanks.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194197/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255385/.

Answer (score 5):

`login` terminates when its child (the logged-in user’s login shell) terminates. It could even `exec` the child without forking, replacing itself, but it needs to take care of PAM session clean-up, so it has to wait for its child instead. Once it terminates, `getty` or `init` (more generally, the init process) do some more clean-up (`utmp` etc.) and wait for a new login (if `getty` replaced itself with `login`, or exits when `login` terminates, the init process will start a new `getty`).

You’re right, under Linux at least, `login` is generally only used on virtual consoles (or real terminals connected via serial devices). Graphical display managers implement their own login mechanisms. You *can* run `login` inside a login shell, *e.g.* in a terminal emulator, with a little care (`exec login`); a long time ago, recursive `login` was used to change users, the equivalent of `su` nowadays.

Note that some shells do have a `logout` command, which is supposed to be used instead of `exit` to exit a login shell; in such shells, `exit` typically won’t exit from a login shell.