# Unable to see agetty ttyS0 in process list when connected with serial console

Tags: linux, ps

I am using ttyS0 as a serial console to connect to a redhat linux, which is setup using `/etc/init/ttyS0.conf`.

When I am connected to serial console, could not find `agetty` process however sees a `bash` shell on `ttyS0`. Whereas with SSH, I could see `agetty` process in process listing. How this work, does bash kill agetty and get itself on ttyS0 when connecting over console.

```
# /etc/init/ttyS0.conf

#
 stop on runlevel [S016]
 start on runlevel [23]
#
 respawn
instance /dev/ttyS0
 exec agetty -h -L -w /dev/ttyS0 115200 vt102
#
```

no `agetty` process when connecting over console, however I see `bash` process with ttyS0

```
virsh # console --domain 1
Connected to domain LMS
Escape character is ^]
login: root
Password:
Last login: Fri Nov  9 03:33:11 from 192.168.122.1
[root@lmm ~]# ps -eaf | grep -i agetty
root      8397  8376  0 03:37 ttyS0    00:00:00 grep -i agetty
[root@lmm ~]#

[root@lmm ~]# ps -eaf | grep -i ttyS0
root      8376  5585  0 03:37 ttyS0    00:00:00 -bash
```

`agetty` process when connecting over SSH to machine

```
[root@lmm ~]# ps -eaf | grep -i agetty
root      5585     1  0 03:32 ttyS0    00:00:00 agetty -h -L -w /dev/ttyS0 115200 vt102
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect using a terminal managed by `agetty`, which is the case here when you connect over the serial port, `agetty` replaces itself with `login` without forking (see [the implementation in `util-linux`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/term-utils/agetty.c?id=c094fcd373dacd3283b9f547c9a856ab21eb6484#n561)). So once you’ve logged in, there is no `agetty` process any more.

See also [When will login terminate?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/441678/86440)