# Login prompt's weird behaviour

Tags: login, tty, prompt

In TTY, my login prompt has got a strange and annoying behaviour: with my arrow keys, I can move the cursor everywhere on the screen, including the prompt itself, the welcome message, etc. If I press the `del` key, the character under the cursor is replaced by a black space. It also happens with my login name, so if I make a misprint, I cannot correct it and the tty becomes useless. What should I do?

Running openSuSE Leap 15.1 on x86-64.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't strange.  The terminal device simply has echo on with the `echoctl` flag set off in the line discipline.  Usually the terminal device line discipline is reset to a "sane" state by whatever program opens the terminal and chains to `login`, which varies wildly in the general case but is likely one of the many `getty` programs in your case.  (Other possibilities are systemd or `vc-reset-tty`, for example; or ttymon if one is going beyond Linux operating systems.)  Find out what program you are using, and why it is not resetting `echoctl`.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316279/5132
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`vc-reset-tty`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/vc-reset-tty.xml). *nosh Guide*. Softwares.